# How do I cache external api response per user in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I have a rails 4.1 application wherein I have a bookings section. In this section I have multiple sub sections such as Hotels, Vacation rentals etc.

In each of these sections I am fetching data from relevant apis which user can sort and filter.

I would like to cache response per user so that once I have got the data, filtering & sorting is quick with cached data and time is not wasted on making another trip to the other site.

However one issue is users can do this even without logging in.

I have setup memcached store which caches the data fine for the first user but, when second user comes data for first user gets overwritten.

How can I cache data per user(logggd/unlogged) ? (I am willing to change the cache store provided I don't have to spend anything extra for it to work)

Comment: Have you checked Redis?

Comment: Can Redis save user specific data for unlogged users ?

Answer (score 1):

Rails actually supports per user "caches" out of the box. Its called the session. By default Rails uses cookies as storage but you can easily swap the storage to use Memcached or Redis to bypass the ~4kB size limit imposed on cookies by the browser.

To use Rails with memcached as the storage backend use the [Dalli gem](https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli):

```
# Gemfile
gem 'dalli'

# config/environments/production.rb
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

This will let you store pretty much anything by:

```
session[:foo] = bar
```

And the session values can be fetched as long as the user retains his cookie containing the session id.

An alternate approach if you want to keep the performance benefits of using CookieStore for sessions is to use the session id as part of the key used to cache the request in Memcached which would give each user an individual cache.

You can get the session id by calling `session.id` in the controller.

```
require 'dalli'
options = { :namespace => "app_v1", :compress => true }
dc = Dalli::Client.new('localhost:11211', options)
cache_key = 'foo-' + session.id

@data = dc.fetch(cache_key) do
  do_some_api_call
end
```

You can do this with view fragments and the regular rails low level cache as well. Just be note that models are not session aware.

See:

- http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: Isn't rails session only for logged in users. Can I save user specific data even for unlogged users ? If yes what is the limit in MB/KB's ?

Comment: No the session is a simple mechanism that links a cookie with an id to a session storage. Unless you have disabled the sessions middleware every visitor has a session - regardless if you have an authentication system in place that "logs in" users or not. If fact the session is just the building block which you build session based auth systems like Devise on.

Comment: The limit depends entirely on the session storage being used. The limit on cookies is somewhere around 4kb but may vary depending on the browser. The limits on memcached and redis are larger but depend entirely on the server config. I would recommend you read the two articles I linked to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Max. I was unaware of the basic session mechanism and it seems that I can use it with dalli or redis. However I would love to have a caching system where I can delete cache specific to a user.
Right now I am trying to implement this with memory_store but would surely like to give dalli/redis + session id a try in future.

Comment: The thing is I will have multiple keys per user (around 10/12) and I guess it would be easier to achieve this with memory_store.

Comment: This is such a useful answer. Thank you. And you forgot to set expiration time `dc.fetch(cache_key, expires_in: 300) do`